# Django query for many to one relationship

Tags: django, django-models

I have three models, one topic can have zero or more questions, one question can have zero or many answers. Only one answer is right.

They are many to one relationship.

```
class Topic(models.Model):

class Question(models.Model):
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic)

class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question) 
    isright = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Right')
```

Now I tried to loop the question based on topic, how can I achieved it with template?

```
<topic>

  <question>
    <answer>
    <answer>
    <answer>
    <answer>

  <question>
    <answer>
    <answer>
    <answer>
    <answer>
```

How can I add a paginator for question?

```
paginator = Paginator(topic.question_set.all(), 25)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I have understood well, you want to loop over answers ordered by 'topic':

```
answers = Answer.objects.order_by('question__topic', 'question')
```

or:

```
for topic in Topic.objects.all():
    for question in topic.question_set.all():
        for answer in question.answer_set.all():
            ...do something...
```

In templates you can do the same, providing the variable `topics` as Topic.objects.all():

```
{% for topic in topics %}
    {% for question in topic.question_set.all %}
        {% for answer in question.answer_set.all %}
            ...do something...
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This will fork, but will execute so many queries, that DB server will start thinking about the suicide after the 10th requst.

Comment: :) the first query should be faster. Of course Marvin db backends will be discouraged...

Comment: How to add the paginator to the number of question?

Answer (score 1):

Use the *_set.all() variable:

```
 t = Topic.objects.get(id=X)
 questions = t.question_set.all()

 for q in questions:
     answers = q.answer_set.all()

     for a in answers:
          print a
```

Comment: How can I do this in template?

Answer (score 0):

```
topic_instance.question_set.all()
```

See the  [docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward)